# Does the `Number` type in Google Document AI include decimals?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai, google-ai-platform

I've been using the document AI tool for a while and have quite a few documents labeled and just thought of a question: does the `Number` field type allow for decimals (ex: `0.3456`) or does it only allow for whole numbers?

In the case that it doesn't allow for decimals, would using plain text and converting it within post-processing be the next best option?

Have been labeling documents and just thought of this question.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation about creating dataset schemas](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/create-dataset#:%7E:text=Number%3A%20a%20number%20%2D%20integer%20or%20floating%20point.)

> `Number`: a number - integer or floating point.

Yes, the `Number` label type supports decimal values.

Comment: Thanks for the response, my bad for missing that easy find! I also had a follow-up question: if the numbers within my document include commas (ex: `1,234.23`), can I still have that type be a `Number` or would it be wiser to just capture it as plain text and convert it in post-processing?

Comment: It should be fine as a number even if there's a comma.

Comment: Appreciate the response, thanks!